# Unexpected top level exception: bad class file magic, in Android

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, ant

I am trying to compile my android program via command line, using ANT. And the code compiles fine. But when the target `-dex` is executed, I get the following error:

```
 [dex] input: /Users/aditya/Desktop/workspace/Java/Play/bin/classes
      [dex] input: /Library/Java/Android/tools/support/annotations.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed annotations-5bd0afe28d834ceff67df1063f0f145b.jar <- /Library/Java/Android/tools/support/annotations.jar
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /Users/aditya/Desktop/workspace/Java/Play/bin/classes.dex...
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/adi/play/BuildConfig.class
       [dx] 
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/adi/play/PlayActivity$1.class
       [dx] 
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/adi/play/PlayActivity$2.class
       [dx] 
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/adi/play/PlayActivity.class
       [dx] 
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/adi/play/R$attr.class
       [dx] 
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/adi/play/R$drawable.class
       [dx] 
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/adi/play/R$id.class
       [dx] 
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/adi/play/R$layout.class
       [dx] 
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/adi/play/R$string.class
       [dx] 
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/adi/play/R.class
       [dx] 
       [dx] 10 errors; aborting

BUILD FAILED
/Library/Java/Android/tools/ant/build.xml:899: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Library/Java/Android/tools/ant/build.xml:901: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Library/Java/Android/tools/ant/build.xml:913: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Library/Java/Android/tools/ant/build.xml:294: null returned: 1
```

I get the same kind of error with Gradle and IntelliJ.

I am not able to figure out the actual problem whats happening. Please Help.
I am using Java 1.8 to compile this program. Is there no way of using Java 1.8 to do this? Is it necessary to use 1.6? If so, how should I use Java 1.6?

Comment: It looks like you are using JAVA 8 to build your project. Current version of dex is not working with Java 8. Try to build with java 7.

Comment: @Demand: Apologies, I didn't see your comment until I'd posted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the version of Java you are using to compile your classes.

You need to be using Java 6 or 7 for Android development. Java 7 support was added more recently and its functionality is limited, so use 6 for maximum compatibility.

Comment: You have no idea, sir. How big a help it was. I was filleling with this thing for over a week. I searched the whole internet. But didn't get this. Thanks a tonne.

Answer (score 1):

the reason of this problem is java version. It should be jdk 1.7 or less. uninstall your 1.8 version and install 1.7 and change the path in environment variables.