# "Bad class file magic" from setting up Android Studio for NDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm setting up a project to work with [Androids NDK](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview). By that I have to [use the experimental Gradle plugin.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) Gradle syncs without errors and the make is without errors.
But when I try to 'run app' Gradle gives this error message:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic
>   (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)   at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)    ...
>   19 more

From [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863007/unexpected-top-level-exception-bad-class-file-magic-in-android) I can see that it might depend on me using Java 8 and Android requiring Java 7. But my other projects compile and run without this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I missed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32400935/1743457) and the code snippet that solved the problem.

```
model {
    android {
        compileOptions.with {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        ... //rest of gradle code
    }
}
```

Sloppy research from my side.